# Minimum column width using fixed table layout

Tags: html, css, html-table, fixed, column-width

I have a problem I've been struggling with for a long while now. I'm trying to build a repeated table design where I have two rows with key value pairs and then another row with a single column which should span across both the above columns. Like this:

Key: Value

Key: Value

Comment

Key: Value

Key: Value

Comment

... and so forth.

Shortly, the idea is to build a message wall.

I want the first key to only take up minimum required width, no more, no less (except for the padding). And then I want the value to fill the rest of the space, but it should begin right after the value.

I have managed to get the key column to take up minimum width, but that was without using `table-layout:fixed`, but that brought me other problems (the table content going outside the parent div for example). So, I would like to have a fixed table layout as decribed, but with the content not flowing outside the parent div... I know I "fix" it using different CSS depending on the viewers screen size (setting a specific width for the first column) - but is that the best and only(?) solution?

Part of the code:

```css
.divContainer {
  width: 500px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.topTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;

}
td {
    width: auto; 
}
td.tableKey {
    padding-left: 7px;
    width: 1px;
    color: red;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
td.tableValue {
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 200px;
}    
td.tableComment {
       white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
        white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div class="divContainer">
    <table class="topTable">
        <tr>
            <td class="tableKey">Key:</td>
            <td class="tableValue">Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tableKey">Key:</td>
            <td class="tableValue">Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="tableComment">This is a dummy messageeeeeeeeeeeeeeemessageeeeeeeeeeeeeeemessageeeeeeeeeeeeeeemessageeeeeeeeeeeee.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/x87mwe4c/1/

Any help would be appreciated, been trying more or less everything. The code supplied is the "current" version - but tried much other stuff as well without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can work with a table. But most just use flex styling these days. An example:

```css
.message-wall {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 500px;
  list-style-type: none;
  
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.message-row {
  display: flex;
}

.comment {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
.tableKey {
  flex: 0 0 0;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  
  color: red;
}
.tableValue {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="message-wall">
  <li id="message-1">
    <div class="message-row">
      <span class="tableKey">Key:</span>
      <span class="tableValue">Value</span>
    </div>
    <div class="message-row">
      <span class="tableKey">Key:</span>
      <span class="tableValue">Value</span>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">This is a dummy messageeeeeeeeeeeeeeemessageeeeeeeeeeeeeeemessageeeeeeeeeeeeeeemessageeeeeeeeeeeee</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yay! Both yours and Omukiguys solution works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help, greatly appreciated. Is any solution preferred above the other when it comes to rendering time etc? If I'd for example have around 200-300 posts in the wall?

Comment: It will depend on how much value you want to put on browser support. Both techniques are relative new. However flex existed a lot longer and so has better browser support. While grid is still brand new:

https://i.imgur.com/xSG0VBJ.png

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess IE 11 support would be quite good... so I guess I'll go for the flex-design. As you're code suggests, I suppose that using ul and li tags is the recommended way? Thanks again!

Comment: It doesn't really matter what tags you are using. You can perfectly use any tag available in html (div's for example). It's also possible with the table tags as well.

Comment: I have updated the code, maybe that can give you some ideas. Good luck ;)

Comment: I see, that's great. Thank you very much again! :)

Comment: I recognized that the word-wrapping doesn't seem to work as expected using the flex-design. I've tried getting it to work but word-wrap: break-word; doesn't seem to work at all. Searched a lot but haven't found any working solution except for the break-word: break-all; which isn't suitable for me since it breaks every word, even short ones incase they end up in the wrong place...

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried setting the display as a block and using the flexbox as a wrapper?

Comment: @JensIngels caniuse.com gives updated results so keep checking.

Comment: Thanks Jens, yes, I tried setting the display as a block while creating a flexbox wrapper (if you just mean a surrounding div with the display: flex attribute. That did unfortunately not work, overflow: hidden is unfortunately not suitable either since it removes the overflowing content..

Comment: I believe that are about the limitations of word breaking you can have in css and most of them aren't even supported by most browsers. 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/

You can do it manually with a script like is show here:
https://johnresig.com/blog/injecting-word-breaks-with-javascript/

I found something on github but it feels incompleet:
https://gist.github.com/bgrayburn/44fa018b94222590f618

Comment: Overal, I really don't recommand in putting effect into word breaking. It's basicly a total different question now.

Comment: I finally got it working, I don't understand why it worked, but when I changed the tag containing the comment from a div to a p tag, the word-wrapping started working (without using break-all), in all browsers. So now I finally got a working layout. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Next time please properly format your request first. Example post updated to match main request.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the css Grid solution. Here you go. I have changed your mark up too. I have added a fallback CSS solution for the non grid browsers. You can test it, it works. I have used the traditional floats and then incorporated the css grid for modern browsers to overwrite the old CSS.

You can share your views.

```css
/*CSS box model reset for different browsers*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*CSS for non grid support browsers*/
.divContainer {
  background: blue;
  /*you can change the size as you wish*/
  width: 500px;
}

.tableKey  {
  background: #ce3;
  float: left;
  /*Set a size for the float css to work*/
  width: 50px;
}

.tableValue {
  float: left;
  /*Occupy the rest of the space minus 50px for the tablekey width*/
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  background: #a03;
  clear: right;
}

.longContent {
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: pre-line;
  /*Let the block take up the next portion down without being floated to left.*/
  clear: both;
}

/*If the browser supports grid then use the CSS below instead of the fallback above. CSS is hierarchical. The CSS below the other is read first. e.g I have overwritten the background of .divContainer in the lines below*/

.divContainer {
  background: cyan;
}

@supports (display: grid) {
  .divContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    /*Divide the layout into two columns. The first column takes the minimum space it needs but not beyond 50px; While the rest of the remaining space is taken up by the second div.*/
    grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 50px) 1fr;
  }
  
  /*Introduced width:auto in .tableKey and .tableValue to overwrite the width from the non-grid support css*/
  .tableKey  {
    background: #ce3;
    width: auto;
  }

  .tableValue {
    background: #a03;
    width: auto;
  }
  .longContent {
    /*Span this row by 2 spans of the layout*/
    grid-column: span 2;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre-line;
    /*Overwrite clear from the non-grid support */
    clear: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="divContainer">
  <div class="tableKey">Key:</div>
  <div class="tableValue">Value</div>
  <div class="tableKey">Key:</div>
  <div class="tableValue">Value</div>
  <div class="longContent">This is a dummy messageeeeeeeeeeeeeeemessageeeeeeeeeeeeeeemessageeeeeeeeeeeeeeemessageeeeeeeeeeeee.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yay! Both yours and Jens solution works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help, greatly appreciated. Is any solution preferred above the other when it comes to rendering time etc? If I'd for example have around 200-300 posts in the wall?

Comment: I know CSS grid isn't really supported by IE11, but I've still tried getting your solution running properly using IE11. I used display: -ms-grid together with display: grid, as well as adding -ms-grid-columns: auto minmax(min-content, 1fr); for the container. And for the longContent I added -ms-grid-column-span: 2; Unfortunately it was just a mess... Tried a bit other stuff too without any success.

Should I just give trying up or do you have any ideas? Thanks big time.

Comment: Let write a fall back for you. If you look at caniuse.com and search a CSS feature it gives you a proper direction on features to use. Modern browsers like edge support both flexbox and grid.

Comment: I have added some changes.

Comment: Thank you very, very much! That works perfectly using IE and Chrome, unfortunately I recognized now that the word-wrap does not function using Firefox (latest version) unless I add the -moz-hyphens attribute, then the word-wrapping -behavior- is changed into something close to word-break: break-all.. :(

Comment: I will check the prefixing and respond accordingly

Comment: Thanks, I didn't manage to get it working in firefox without using break-all, which unfortunately isn't "good enough". But I finally got Jens flex solution working perfectly, so I'll go for that one. Thank you very much for your help!